# Issues with Postgres authentication during integration tests with docker

Tags: docker, authentication, docker-compose, knex.js, postgresql-9.5

Problem is while running integration tests, i receive this error:

```
 error: password authentication failed for user "postgres"
      at Connection.parseE (node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:567:11)
      at Connection.parseMessage (node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:391:17)
```

This happens 100% of the time regardless of what is in the `docker-compose.yml` file.

I'm using knex to make the DB connection like so:

```
    function getConnectionForDatabase(database) {
     return {
       host: config.get("database.connection.host"),
       user: config.get("database.connection.user"),
       password: config.get("database.connection.password"),
       database: database
     };
   }

   function getDatabaseConnection(database) {
     return knex({
       client: config.get("database.client"),
       connection: getConnectionForDatabase(database),
       debug: config.get("database.debugMode"),
       pool: {
         min: config.get("database.pool.min"),
         max: config.get("database.pool.max")
       }
     });
   }
```

`getDatabaseConnection("postgres");`

host is 127.0.0.1 and lets say the username is `postgres` and the password is `postgres`

the `docker-compose.yml` contains:

```
   postgres:
    image: postgres:9.5.4
    command: postgres -D /var/lib/postgresql/data
    volumes:
      - db-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: 'postgres'
      POSTGRES_USER: 'postgres'
```

and i can connect to the postgres db manually using:

```
docker exec -it <hash> bash
root@<hash>:/# psql -U postgres
```

ive also updated the password to make the `docker-compose.yml` file and it wont connect:

`psql -d postgres -c "ALTER USER postgres WITH PASSWORD '<new password>';"`

Yet, I run the unit test... i get the same error message as mentioned above!!

What am i missing to get this run? Any help would be incredibly appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to connect your database with `psql postgres://postgres:postgres@localhost:5432/database` from your host machine. If that does not work you have problem with your docker psql server. The way you are currently testing your connection might use unix sockets to connect the server, so it doesn't verify that your server is accepting connections through TCP socket.

If TCP connection with `psql` works fine, try to print out your used knex configurations to make sure there are no `undefined` values passed to any of connection attributes. First you should try to connect with hardcoded parameters, before trying to do anything more complicated.

Comment: Yeah, ive checked the configuration data. There is all good and it doesn't come up as undefined.

Will try an connect to the DB via my machine and see if it works! thanks for that idea.

Comment: Is it possible to remove the password requirement for a Docker instance? Meaning switching the`host all all 0.0.0.0/0 md5` to `trusted` during the docker-compose up process.

Haven't seen much documentation on how to do it. wondering if it's possible